# Xcode 8.2.1 Stuck Compiling asset catalogs

Tags: ios, xcode

I can run the app when I am not using any of the images in my assets folder. But as soon as I use one of the images, when I try to run the build it gets stuck "compiling asset catalogs" and never runs.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

I have tried to restart my computer and clean my build folder but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the folder in which I have images.xcassets (iOS folder) was not linked correctly. So updating the folder path did the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.